# where is Linux driver for PHP accessing MS SQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

I got the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server from:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

However, these drivers are for Windows bases operating systems. Are there any such drivers for Linux (Ubuntu the best)? Thank you for the information!

Comment: You could use PostgresQL or MariaDB on Linux. Otherwise, look for a DB-neutral SQL connector.

Answer (score 2):

See the link below:
To access SQL Server from PHP on Linux, we used Easysoft ODBC drivers with PHP on RedHat and Ubuntu (Edgy Eft, Feisty Fawn, Gutsy Gibbon and Hardy Heron). Easysoft ODBC drivers should work with any recent 32-bit or 64-bit Linux distribution—CentOS, Debian GNU/Linux, Fedora, Kubuntu, Mandrake/Mandriva, OpenSUSE/SUSE, RedHat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), Slackware and so on.

http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html